# What would be the necessary & sufficient cond.s for the distribution of $\bar X$ the same as $X_i$s if $X_i$s are i.d but not Gaussian r.v.s?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem

Let us have a set of random variables $\{X_i\}_{i=1,2,...,n}$, where $X_i$s are identically distributed and are **not** a Gaussian random variables.

The central limit theorem states that if $X_i$ and $X_j$ are independent for all $i\not =j$, then 
$$\bar X = \sum_i X_i/n$$
is (approximately) a Gaussian random variable.

**Question:**

However, what would the necessary and sufficient conditions for the distribution of $\bar X$ be the same as $X_i$s ?

---

For example, if we know that $X_i$s are mutually correlated in a specific way - hence they are not independent, the central theorem would not be valid, hence the distribution of $\bar X$ would (possible) be different that of Gaussian one.

**Edit:** My main goal by asking this question is that if I have a bunch of identically distributed random variables, then I would like to see the same distribution in their mean, i.e $\overline X$. In a way, carry the distribution to the distribution of their mean.

Comment: If you allow $X_i$s to be independent as well, then $\bar X$ has the same distribution as that of $X_i$ for the Cauchy distribution in addition to the Normal distribution. These are examples of [stable distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution).

Comment: @StubbornAtom I am confused: if $X_i$s are i.i.d. Cauchy r.v.s, then according to the wiki article, $\bar X$ is a Cauchy r.v. also. How does it not contract with C.L.T?

Comment: CLT gives asymptotic distribution only. But since moments like mean, variance do not exist for Cauchy distribution, classical CLT does not hold here.